# Index of each element within list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have something like the following list of lists:

```
>>> mylist=[['A','B','C'],['D','E'],['F','G','H']]
```

I want to construct a new list of lists where each element is a tuple where the first value indicates the index of that item within its sublist, and the second value is the original value.

I can obtain this using the following code:

```
>>> final_list=[]
>>> for sublist in mylist:
...     slist=[]
...     for i,element in enumerate(sublist):
...         slist.append((i,element))
...     final_list.append(slist)
... 
>>> 
>>> final_list
[[(0, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (2, 'C')], [(0, 'D'), (1, 'E')], [(0, 'F'), (1, 'G'), (2, 'H')]]
>>>
```

Is there a better or more concise way to do this using list comprehension?

Comment: This _might_ be a better fit for code view: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
final_list = [list(enumerate(l)) for l in mylist]
```

Comment: Why not just do `list(enumerate(l))` instead of the inner comprehension?